# Multipart boundary in django rest framework renderer

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I've written a Custom Renderer in Django Rest Framework to write a Multipart Mixed response.  These have a boundary separating all the parts of the response.  This boundary must appear in the Content Type header.

I can't see how the best way of injecting a custom boundary into an instance of the renderer once it's been created as the renderer, the Accept header and the media type seem so closely tied.

I'd like my renderer to create this type of response:

```
----boundary-65d4d397-cf77-41c2-a88d-3ef52e806032
Content-Type: application/json

[{"some": "json"}]
----boundary-65d4d397-cf77-41c2-a88d-3ef52e806032
Content-Type: text/plain

This is some text.

----boundary-65d4d397-cf77-41c2-a88d-3ef52e806032--
```

with the header:

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=----boundary-65d4d397-cf77-41c2-a88d-3ef52e806032
```

How to do this in Django Rest Framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do this by adding a "boundary" property to my custom renderer and patching DRF's response.py to use it.

In response.py, I've removed the existing Content Type detection code to after rendering, to allow the boundary to be generated by the renderer at runtime (to allow use of random strings in each boundary).  Here's the new Content Type detection code for response.py.

```
boundary = renderer.boundary if hasattr(renderer, "boundary") else None
if not content_type:
    content_type = "{0}".format(media_type)
    if charset is not None:
        content_type += "; charset={0}".format(charset)
    if boundary is not None:
        content_type += "; boundary={0}".format(boundary)
self['Content-Type'] = content_type
```

I'm now maintaining a branch of Django Rest Framework that does this, should anyone need it.

https://github.com/st8st8/django-rest-framework